# Xdebug Profiler not working over apache

Tags: php, xdebug, xdebug-profiler

The issue is I get no output from Xdebug-Profiler if I request any page from my server over browser. If i call a script with php in terminal like

```
php /var/www/html/index.php
```

then the profiler's output will be created. So I guess my configurations are fine. Here the important setting from my phpinfo:

```
xdebug.profiler_aggregate   Off Off
xdebug.profiler_append  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable  On  On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger  Off Off
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger_value    no value    no value
xdebug.profiler_output_dir  /home/duser/profiler /home/duser/profiler
xdebug.profiler_output_name testgrind.out.%t-%s testgrind.out.%t-%s
```

The output from https://xdebug.org/wizard.php for my phpinfo:

```
   Xdebug installed: 2.5.4
   Server API: Apache 2.0 Handler
   Windows: no
   Zend Server: no
   PHP Version: 5.6.30
   Zend API nr: 220131226
   PHP API nr: 20131226
   Debug Build: no
   Thread Safe Build: no
   Configuration File Path: /etc
   Configuration File: /etc/php.ini
   Extensions directory: /usr/lib64/php/modules
   You're already running the latest Xdebug version
```

I have read a lot of topics here, where people had similar problem and it was often rights issue. Therefore i created the profiler folder in my home directory with rights like:

```
   drwxrwxrwx   2 duser duser  140 30. Jun 07:02 profiler
```

The server is running on Centos 7, SELinux is disabled. The Xdebug-debugger works fine. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873836/why-xdebug-doesnt-work-in-apache I read, that there are two php.inis - one for php and one for apache. But Phpinfo shows the current settigs, doesn't it ? Anyway i set above settings in httpd.conf with php_value as well, but it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue was, apache had no access to my /home/duser/profiler folder. The output from xdebug has to be saved in /var/www/html/  or the configuration needs adjustment, so that apache will have access to specific path.